# Calculate integral with $\Gamma$ and $B$

Tags: integration, special-functions

The integration is like:
$$\int_{a}^{b}\left(\frac{b-x}{x-a}\right)^{p}dx$$
with $0<p<1$

Answer is $(b-a)p \frac{\pi}{\sin p\pi}$

> Apparently, we can reversely construct $$\Gamma(1-p) \Gamma(p) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi p}$$
>   but when I continue I find that I can't transform the old interval into the $(0,1)$ which is needed by $B$ function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to substitute $$x=(b-a)t+a \;\text{ where }t\in [0,1]$$
Then use the beta function $$B(x,y) =\int_{0}^{1} t^{x-1}(1-t)^{y-1} dt =\cfrac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$